# vue nuxt, passing API value on header title SEO

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

how can i pass my api Value to Header title on vue? im using nuxt.

I try using this but i got error 'blog is not defined'

```
async asyncData({params, error}) {
        try {
            let topBlogger = await axios.get('http://api.bla.bla/API/topblogger.php')
            let isi = await axios.get(`http://api.bla.bla/API/news.php?id_artikel=${+params.id}`)
            let tagList = await axios.get('https://api.bla.bla/users')
            return {
                bloggers: topBlogger.data,
                blog: isi.data,
                tags: tagList.data,

            }
        } catch (e) {
            error({message: 'User not found', statusCode: 404})
        }
    },
head () {

        return {
            title: blog.id_artikel+' | title bla bla',
            meta: [
                { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'content dll' }
            ]
        }
    },
```

but when i use blog on `<template></template>` it work
i'm new on vueJS so still can't seem understand well how it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access data using this

```
return {
            title: this.blog.id_artikel+' | title bla bla',
            meta: [
                { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'content dll' }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: thanks it work, i don't know if the solution is that's simple. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful for you.

```
<script>
export default {
 head: {
 title: this.blog.id_artikel+' | title bla bla',
 meta: [
 {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: 'Home page description'
      }
    ],
  }
}
</script>
```